# SharePoint designer 2013 keeps asking for credentials

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

SharePoint designer 2013 keeps asking for credentials when I try to open site to modify it I have SharePoint designer 2013 and front end server SharePoint 2013

I tried the following steps to fix it but also not working with me:

- scenario one:

> Get Tools –> Internet Options in IE and go to Security tab.
>   Add my site to the Trusted Sites. Then click on Custom Level in Security tab, and select Automatic logon with current user name and password option under User Authentication – Logon.

- scenario two:

> Create the Local Security Authority host names that can be referenced in an NTLM authentication request
>
> Create the Local Security Authority host names that can be referenced in an NTLM authentication request. Click Start, click Run, type Regedit, and then click OK. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`
>
> Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value. In the Name column, type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER. Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify. In the Value data box, type the CNAME or the DNS alias, that is used for the local shares on the computer, and then click OK.

- scenario three:

> Disable the authentication loopback check
>
> Re-enable the behavior that exists in Windows Server 2003 by setting the DisableLoopbackCheck registry entry in the
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` registry
>   subkey to 1. To set the DisableLoopbackCheck registry entry to 1, follow these steps on the client computer: Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>
> Locate and then click the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value. Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
>   In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK. Exit Registry Editor. Restart the computer.

The three scenarios suppose to make you working but in my case not working.

Answer (score 2):

hi check with these settings Go to – IIS Manager – Expand Sites – select share point central Administration- Authentication – windows Authentication – Advanced Settings – select Enable kernel-mode authentication- select ok

for the first time you have to enter the credentials which you have given while configuring

Answer (score 1):

I tried resetting IIS -- did not work.

I tried going to IIS manager or run inetmgr and tried to go to the site that I am working on changed the Authentication by disabling basic settings and enabling Windows Authentication, set Advanced Settings to Accept & tick check on enable kernel mode. It did not work, it still asked for my credentials. My problem even extended to my SharePoint 2013 site.

What ultimately fixed my issue:

I disabled Windows Authentication, enabled basic settings so I can log on to my SP 2013 site. Go to IE settings; add my site to Trusted sites & untick "REQUIRE SERVER VERIFICATION (https:) for all sites in zone;" Local internet & clicked on custom level and chose Automatic logon only on Intranet zone; and after applying everything, I restarted the computer.

When I logged back to my SharePoint site, it is fine. I tried my site on SharePoint Designer and it was able to access my site.

It took me two days to fix my issue and I'd tried several workaround but, ultimately, the fix I posted worked for me. I hope it will work for you.